# A word to describe two (far apart) locations

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I'm looking for a word to describe locations that are far apart. My sentence is:

> The manufacturer uses two ***_*____** locations, thus requiring two inspectors.

Comment: *Remote* should do the trick, given the context provided by "thus requiring two inspectors". Otherwise stick to *far apart*. So, "... uses two remote locations..." or "... uses two locations that are far apart...".

Comment: This is almost right, though it could mean that both locations are remote, as opposed to remote from each other.

Comment: Yes it could. That's why I said "given the context". Given that you write "thus requiring two inspectors", remoteness from each other is implied. If these two locations were distant (from you) but close to each other then you would not need two inspectors. CAVEAT-- My suggestions are based on the assumption that there is a headquarters which is in a different place entirely. This assumption has to do with your use of the word "inspectors", which (to me) implies a central place whence inspectors venture forth to do their duty.

Comment: Maybe _distant_ will work too.

Answer (score 4):

In your example, the necessity of two inspectors arises because there are two plants for the manufacturer. I would go for *separate*:

> The manufacturer uses two **separate** locations, thus requiring two inspectors.

If you want to talk about the distance of their separation, you could have:

> The manufacturer uses two separate locations **spaced far apart**, thus requiring two inspectors.

Or you could use *distant*:

> The manufacturer uses two **distant** locations, thus requiring two inspectors.

Comment: It is this phrase 'spaced far apart' that I was hoping to find a single word for.

Comment: Try distant, it should do: The manufacturer uses two *distant* locations, thus requiring two inspectors.

Answer (score 2):

As has been pointed out, words like *distant* or *remote* don't really work in this case, because they normally mean *far away from **here*** (or, perhaps, from the manufacturers headquarters).

A common two-word alternative is [widely separated](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22two%20widely%20separated%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) (hyphenated or not according to choice).

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

The manufacturer uses two `globalized` locations, thus requiring two inspectors.

EDIT:

Or, The manufacturer uses two `distant` locations, thus requiring two inspectors.

Comment: Globalized makes me think of locations in two different countries, or even continent, which may not be the case here.

Answer (score 1):

I see your quandary: words like *remote* and *distant* can be construed to mean that the two locations are, say, far apart from a headquarters, as opposed to being faraway from each other.  Really, you're looking for an antonym for *nearby*.

One thesaurus I consulted listed two synonyms for *apart* as: *away from each other, distant from each other*, indicating this might be difficult to capture in a single word.

If you want to avoid ambiguity, maybe something like this would work best:

> The manufacturer uses two **separate and far apart** locations, thus
>   requiring two inspectors.

Or maybe:

> Because the manufacturer uses two locations **sitauated far from each other**, two
>   inspectors are required.

Or even:

> The manufacturer uses two locations **in separate cities**, thus
>   requiring two inspectors.

```
or counties, or states, or provinces, or countries
```

However, if you're bent on retaining your original construct, and using a single word, I might offer:

> The manufacturer uses two **spread** locations, thus requiring two
>   inspectors.

Or, use *separate*, as Shyam suggested, and rely on the "*thus requiring two inspectors*" to provide enough context to imply they are *separate* but not *across town*.

Answer (score 1):

Could you just say the following?

*The manufacturer uses two far-apart locations, thus requiring two inspectors.*

(I would use the hyphen in this case for the adjective phrase before the word locations.)

Answer (score 1):

My first thought is to say "too disparate locations", though that could be taken to mean not that the places are far apart, but rather that the facilities at those places are different in some way, like one is a factory and the other an office building.

Fumble Fingers suggestion of "widely separated" is probably as clear as you're going to get in a minimum of words.

Comment: Snap! My first thought was "disparate" too, but I discarded it on the grounds that this really means "very dissimilar" - far apart in appearance or nature, rather than in distance.